# Atom Package installation error, How do I solve it?

Tags: atom-editor

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAbSi.png)

I was trying to install the necessary files for C++, and I updated Atom, deleted the old MinGW, and was reinstalling MinGW, if that is relevant. then I tried to install extensions for Atom and this error showed up saying file needs an app, I don't know its extension to set a default app, and this error seems to be very rare since I cannot find anything on it anywhere.

Comment: Did this occur after installation, or during installation? Does this occur for all Atom packages, or just this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error looks like your OS doesn't have a URI handler for `atom://` set up. In order to do so, you can go to the Atom settings and register it in the *URI Handling* tab:

[image]

Alternatively, you can always install packages from the *Install* tab of the said Atom settings, or even use the command-line (e.g. `apm install autocomplete-plus`).